# Android google maps api Navigation facility

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing a map related android app, The app is mainly focused about navigation. I have gone through all the documentations in this official google maps api - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/
    But i cant figure out navigation is possible or not. I had two questions.
1. Is it possible to draw navigation inside my app(not by placing an intent to google maps).
2. If its possible then guide some tutorial to attain my goal.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to draw navigation inside my app(not by placing an intent to google maps).

No, the maximum you can get - is route points out of Route API and draw polyline through these lat/lng points. Actual turn-by-turn navigation is not exposed by Google. You need to send an Intent to Navigation app.

Comment: What do you mean "continuously"? Route API takes startPoint and endPoint as parameters and responds with the set of route points (more at [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)). If your current location changed and you need to update your route according to current location - you need to make another request to Route API